# Python time.sleep() blocks thread longer than expected

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, flask, thread-sleep

I have a python(Flask) app that runs one thread that should print time every second, but it seems not working as expected.

weird behaviour (with time.sleep):

```
def pending():
  while True:
    print "time: ", datetime.datetime.now(), threading.current_thread()
    time.sleep(1)

thread = Thread(target = pending, args = ())
thread.start()
```

Output (prints all at once, look at output time on the left). Every print is printed in 13:53:11, instead of every second

```
2017-10-20T13:53:11.569382+00:00 app[web.1]: time:  2017-10-20 13:52:45.544440 <Thread(Thread-1, started 140522956039936)>
2017-10-20T13:53:11.569383+00:00 app[web.1]: time:  2017-10-20 13:52:46.544843 <Thread(Thread-1, started 140522956039936)>
2017-10-20T13:53:11.569384+00:00 app[web.1]: time:  2017-10-20 13:52:47.545041 <Thread(Thread-1, started 140522956039936)>
2017-10-20T13:53:11.569384+00:00 app[web.1]: time:  2017-10-20 13:52:48.545815 <Thread(Thread-1, started 140522956039936)>
2017-10-20T13:53:11.569385+00:00 app[web.1]: time:  2017-10-20 13:52:49.547043 <Thread(Thread-1, started 140522956039936)>
2017-10-20T13:53:11.569385+00:00 app[web.1]: time:  2017-10-20 13:52:50.547821 <Thread(Thread-1, started 140522956039936)>
2017-10-20T13:53:11.569386+00:00 app[web.1]: time:  2017-10-20 13:52:51.549031 <Thread(Thread-1, started 140522956039936)>
2017-10-20T13:53:11.569387+00:00 app[web.1]: time:  2017-10-20 13:52:52.550236 <Thread(Thread-1, started 140522956039936)>
2017-10-20T13:53:11.569387+00:00 app[web.1]: time:  2017-10-20 13:52:53.550584 <Thread(Thread-1, started 140522956039936)>
2017-10-20T13:53:11.569388+00:00 app[web.1]: time:  2017-10-20 13:52:54.551613 <Thread(Thread-1, started 140522956039936)>
2017-10-20T13:53:11.569389+00:00 app[web.1]: time:  2017-10-20 13:52:55.552859 <Thread(Thread-1, started 140522956039936)>
2017-10-20T13:53:11.569389+00:00 app[web.1]: time:  2017-10-20 13:52:56.554084 <Thread(Thread-1, started 140522956039936)>
2017-10-20T13:53:11.569390+00:00 app[web.1]: time:  2017-10-20 13:52:57.555101 <Thread(Thread-1, started 140522956039936)>
2017-10-20T13:53:11.569390+00:00 app[web.1]: time:  2017-10-20 13:52:58.556311 <Thread(Thread-1, started 140522956039936)>
2017-10-20T13:53:11.569391+00:00 app[web.1]: time:  2017-10-20 13:52:59.557522 <Thread(Thread-1, started 140522956039936)>
2017-10-20T13:53:11.569392+00:00 app[web.1]: time:  2017-10-20 13:53:00.558695 <Thread(Thread-1, started 140522956039936)>
2017-10-20T13:53:11.569392+00:00 app[web.1]: time:  2017-10-20 13:53:01.559222 <Thread(Thread-1, started 140522956039936)>
2017-10-20T13:53:11.569393+00:00 app[web.1]: time:  2017-10-20 13:53:02.560393 <Thread(Thread-1, started 140522956039936)>
2017-10-20T13:53:11.569394+00:00 app[web.1]: time:  2017-10-20 13:53:03.561595 <Thread(Thread-1, started 140522956039936)>
2017-10-20T13:53:11.569394+00:00 app[web.1]: time:  2017-10-20 13:53:04.562276 <Thread(Thread-1, started 140522956039936)>
2017-10-20T13:53:11.569395+00:00 app[web.1]: time:  2017-10-20 13:53:05.563509 <Thread(Thread-1, started 140522956039936)>
2017-10-20T13:53:11.569396+00:00 app[web.1]: time:  2017-10-20 13:53:06.564771 <Thread(Thread-1, started 140522956039936)>
2017-10-20T13:53:11.569397+00:00 app[web.1]: time:  2017-10-20 13:53:07.566009 <Thread(Thread-1, started 140522956039936)>
2017-10-20T13:53:11.569398+00:00 app[web.1]: time:  2017-10-20 13:53:08.566247 <Thread(Thread-1, started 140522956039936)>
2017-10-20T13:53:11.569398+00:00 app[web.1]: time:  2017-10-20 13:53:09.566850 <Thread(Thread-1, started 140522956039936)>
2017-10-20T13:53:11.569399+00:00 app[web.1]: time:  2017-10-20 13:53:10.568075 <Thread(Thread-1, started 140522956039936)>
```

Normal behaviour (without time.sleep):

```
def pending():
  while True:
    print "time: ", datetime.datetime.now(), threading.current_thread()

thread = Thread(target = pending, args = ())
thread.start()
```

Output (run as expected, printing all the time):

```
2017-10-20T13:41:00.999954+00:00 app[web.1]: time:  2017-10-20 13:41:00.999677 <Thread(Thread-1, started 140140468745984)>
2017-10-20T13:41:00.999954+00:00 app[web.1]: time:  2017-10-20 13:41:00.999694 <Thread(Thread-1, started 140140468745984)>
2017-10-20T13:41:00.999955+00:00 app[web.1]: time:  2017-10-20 13:41:00.999711 <Thread(Thread-1, started 140140468745984)>
2017-10-20T13:41:00.999955+00:00 app[web.1]: time:  2017-10-20 13:41:00.999728 <Thread(Thread-1, started 140140468745984)>
2017-10-20T13:41:00.999956+00:00 app[web.1]: time:  2017-10-20 13:41:00.999745 <Thread(Thread-1, started 140140468745984)>
2017-10-20T13:41:00.999956+00:00 app[web.1]: time:  2017-10-20 13:41:00.999762 <Thread(Thread-1, started 140140468745984)>
2017-10-20T13:41:00.999956+00:00 app[web.1]: time:  2017-10-20 13:41:00.999780 <Thread(Thread-1, started 140140468745984)>
2017-10-20T13:41:00.999957+00:00 app[web.1]: time:  2017-10-20 13:41:00.999797 <Thread(Thread-1, started 140140468745984)>
2017-10-20T13:41:00.999958+00:00 app[web.1]: time:  2017-10-20 13:41:00.999814 <Thread(Thread-1, started 140140468745984)>
2017-10-20T13:41:00.999958+00:00 app[web.1]: time:  2017-10-20 13:41:00.999831 <Thread(Thread-1, started 140140468745984)>
2017-10-20T13:41:00.999959+00:00 app[web.1]: time:  2017-10-20 13:41:00.999849 <Thread(Thread-1, started 140140468745984)>
2017-10-20T13:41:00.999959+00:00 app[web.1]: time:  2017-10-20 13:41:00.999866 <Thread(Thread-1, started 140140468745984)>
2017-10-20T13:41:00.999962+00:00 app[web.1]: time:  2017-10-20 13:41:00.999883 <Thread(Thread-1, started 140140468745984)>
2017-10-20T13:41:01.000981+00:00 app[web.1]: time:  2017-10-20 13:41:00.999901 <Thread(Thread-1, started 140140468745984)>
2017-10-20T13:41:01.000983+00:00 app[web.1]: time:  2017-10-20 13:41:00.999938 <Thread(Thread-1, started 140140468745984)>
2017-10-20T13:41:01.000983+00:00 app[web.1]: time:  2017-10-20 13:41:00.999975 <Thread(Thread-1, started 140140468745984)>
2017-10-20T13:41:01.000984+00:00 app[web.1]: time:  2017-10-20 13:41:00.999999 <Thread(Thread-1, started 140140468745984)>
2017-10-20T13:41:01.000984+00:00 app[web.1]: time:  2017-10-20 13:41:01.000017 <Thread(Thread-1, started 140140468745984)>
2017-10-20T13:41:01.000985+00:00 app[web.1]: time:  2017-10-20 13:41:01.000035 <Thread(Thread-1, started 140140468745984)>
2017-10-20T13:41:01.000985+00:00 app[web.1]: time:  2017-10-20 13:41:01.000053 <Thread(Thread-1, started 140140468745984)>
2017-10-20T13:41:01.000986+00:00 app[web.1]: time:  2017-10-20 13:41:01.000070 <Thread(Thread-1, started 140140468745984)>
2017-10-20T13:41:01.000986+00:00 app[web.1]: time:  2017-10-20 13:41:01.000087 <Thread(Thread-1, started 140140468745984)>
2017-10-20T13:41:01.000987+00:00 app[web.1]: time:  2017-10-20 13:41:01.000105 <Thread(Thread-1, started 140140468745984)>
```

I also tried with `while not exit_flag.wait(timeout=1):` instead of `while True:` but behaviour is the same

Time is imported as `import time`

Comment: sounds like a stdout flush issue to me.

Comment: It looks like the function really does go round once a second, its just that the lines in the log are produced all at the same time.

Comment: btw, in the first code snippet, what stops function `pending`? It should run forever.

Comment: Nothing stops function, it should run forever because this thread checks the time, and when current time matches with time from db it should run some other functions. But that works correctly, just that output is the problem. @quamrana

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre bro you are the God, THANKS!!